# WinHttpQueryDataAvailable returns various results when downloading data

Tags: c++, winapi, http

I am attempting to download a fairly large file from a site, and will be doing this download several times per day. I am using a loop with `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize)` and `WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer, dwSize, &dwDownloaded)` to continuously read data for the file, until it has been completely downloaded, which is determined when dwSize == 0. However, sometimes I get error codes when downloading the file, specifically 12030 and 12002 (ERROR_WINHTTP_CONNECTION_ERROR and ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT).

What is the best way to add some resilience to the code?  Should I be attempting to reconnect and pick up where I left off? If so, how can this be accomplished with the WinHTTP functions?  The timeout is already reasonably long; could the timeout error actually be a connection error as well?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Whether you retry is entirely up to you and your program. WinINet does support partial downloads but I can't remember the options off hand. Looking through the list in MSDN should give you a hint.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with HTTP, so I'm not sure exactly where in the workflow I should be starting over from, nor how to specify that I have x bytes of a file with total size of y (nor how to handle the case where y has changed). I have spent a fair amount of time googling this issue, reading over MSDN articles; the one for WinHttpQueryDataAvailable seems like an obvious choice, but is unhelpful for this issue.

Comment: I've not done it myself but look at the [`...Range...` query values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385351(v=vs.85).aspx). Another option may be the backing file with the [INTERNET_OPTION_DATAFILE_NAME option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328(v=vs.85).aspx).